# /sys/class/net on Android 12

Tags: shell, internet, system, android-12

Recently, I bought a new phone with Android 12. This command worked on Android 10 (just Termux, no ADB, no root):

```
cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/statistics/rx_bytes
```

but failed on Android 12.

Any work arounds without root? Only shell commands are accepted, not Java/Kotlin and such.

Comment: Apps cannot access `/sys/class/net/`. It's restricted by SELiux policy.

Comment: So, you mean it is _impossible_ (without root) and no workarounds?

Comment: To my knowledge, yes. Not even ADB shell can read `sysfs`. There are Android APIs you may use to get network stats.

Comment: What Android APIs can I use? Best if it is not battery consuming and it must be ran through the command line.

Comment: See [NetworkStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/NetworkStatsManager).